# Wordpress guest can see unauthorized comments

Tags: php, html, wordpress, comments

i created a wordpress comment site with the help of a template for my blog.

The Problem is. If i'm logged in i can see only the approved comments as it should be.
But if i'm logged out, like a Guest, i can see all comments including all unauthorized comments.

This is my code:

```
<?php if (!empty($post->post_password) && $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH]!=$post->post_password) : ?>
    <p id="comments-locked">Please log in to see the comments.</p>
<?php return; endif; ?>

<?php if ($comments) : ?>

<?php 

    $author = array(
            "highlight" => "highlight",
            "email" => "YOUR EMAIL HERE",
            "name" => "YOUR NAME HERE"
    ); 

    $numPingBacks = 0;
    $numComments  = 0;

    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        if (get_comment_type() != "comment") { $numPingBacks++; }
        else { $numComments++; }
    }

    $thiscomment = 'odd';
?>

<?php

    if ($numPingBacks != 0) : ?>

    <h3 class="comments-header"><?php _e($numPingBacks); ?> Trackbacks/Pingbacks</h3>
    <ol id="trackbacks">

<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
<?php if (get_comment_type()!="comment") : ?>

    <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="<?php _e($thiscomment); ?>">
    <?php comment_type(__('Comment'), __('Trackback'), __('Pingback')); ?>:
    <?php comment_author_link(); ?> on <?php comment_date(); ?>
    </li>

    <?php if('odd'==$thiscomment) { $thiscomment = 'even'; } else { $thiscomment = 'odd'; } ?>

<?php endif; endforeach; ?>

    </ol>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php 

    if ($numComments != 0) : ?>

    <h3 class="comments-header"><?php _e($numComments); ?> Comments</h3>
    <ol id="comments">

    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
    <?php if (get_comment_type()=="comment") : ?>

        <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="<?php 

        $this_name = $comment->comment_author;
        $this_email = $comment->comment_author_email;

        if (strcasecmp($this_name, $author["name"])==0 && strcasecmp($this_email, $author["email"])==0)
            _e($author["highlight"]);
        else
            _e($thiscomment); 

        ?>">
            <div class="comment-meta">
                <span class="comment-author"><?php comment_author_link() ?></span>,
                <span class="comment-date"><?php comment_date() ?></span>:
            </div>
            <div class="comment-text">
                <?php comment_text(); ?>
            </div>
        </li>

    <?php if('odd'==$thiscomment) { $thiscomment = 'even'; } else { $thiscomment = 'odd'; } ?>

    <?php endif; endforeach; ?>

    </ol>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php else : 

?>

    <h3 class="comments-header noPandM">There are no comments!</h3>

    <p class="noPandM">Write the first Comment!</p>
    <br />
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (comments_open()) : ?>

    <div id="comments-form">

    <h3 id="comments-header">Write a Comment</h3>
    <p class="commentsSmall"> Your E-Mail will not be published. Required fields are marked. </p>
        <br />
    <?php if (get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
        <p id="comments-blocked">You must be <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=
        <?php the_permalink(); ?>">Login</a> to write a Comment.</p>
    <?php else : ?>

    <form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">

    <?php if ($user_ID) : ?>

    <p>Logged in as <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php">
        <?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>.
        <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=logout"
        title="Log out of this account">Logout</a>
    </p>

    <?php else : ?>

    <p class="commentformlabel"><label for="author">Name<?php if ($req) _e(' (*)'); ?></label></p>
    <p><input type="text" class="commentText" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" size="22" /></p>

    <p class="commentformlabel"><label for="email">E-mail <?php if ($req) _e(' (*)'); ?></label></p>
    <p><input type="text" class="commentText" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email; ?>" size="22" /></p>

    <p class="commentformlabel"><label for="url">Website</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" class="commentText" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url; ?>" size="22" /></p>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <br />
    <p class="commentformlabel"><label for="comment">Comment</label></p>
        <p><textarea name="comment" style="width:80% !important;" id="comment" rows="8"></textarea></p>
            <br />
        <p><button type="submit" name="submit" id="sub">Submit</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></p>

    <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>

    </form>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p id="comments-closed">Sorry, but the Comments are closed in this Area!</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you for reading!
Daniel

Comment: Question whats guests should see? No comments or the same comments as logged in users?

Comment: They should see the same comments as logged in users.

Comment: Can you post when you're defining `$comments`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is when you're requesting the comments.

If you are using `get_comments()` try this:

```
$args = array( 
    'status' => 'approve',
    'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
// pay attention for existing variables with the same name as defined here
```

Comment: I actually have no Idea where $comments come from. As I said i used a template for this. And i can't comprehend where $comments come from. But i did it like you said: <?php 

if ($comments) :

$args = array( 
    'status' => 'approve',
    'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );

 ?> do you think i can do it like this? at least it works!